# How to put values of a given List into a existing dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures

I've got a List with their elements

```py
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and a Dictionary that has their keys and **blank strings** as their values

```py
my_dictionary = {
    'key_a' : '',
    'key_b' : '',
    'key_c' : '',
}
```

The question is: what is the pythonic way to put each one of this list's elements (in this particularly order) as each one of those dictionary values?

Result should be like this:

```py
my_dictionary = {
    'key_a' : 'a',
    'key_b' : 'b',
    'key_c' : 'c',
}
```

Ps: please note that I do not need the dictionary values to be in order after that copy. As well pointed in the comments, after Python 3.7, dictionary's order is not guaranteed anymore

Comment: What is the relationship between the list elements and the dictionary keys? Same order, or same `key_*` suffix, or … ?

Comment: Only for your example, `my_dictionary.update({f"key_{k}": k for k in my_list})` works.

Comment: I have given the code that might be simple to understand. Don't forget to mark as accepted if it helped.

Comment: @Jens I am scrapping a restaurant's menu and the scrapped menu result is a list. But I need each element of the menu cataloged and categorized into this dictionary i've created first

Comment: What Python version are you using? Prior to Python 3.7, dictionary order is not guaranteed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm using 3.7, but i don't need the dictionary keys to be in order after that copy. I'll edit my question to make this point more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
dict(zip(my_dictionary,my_list))
```

Use `.update` method to update your `my_dictionary`.

---

Output

```
{'key_a': 'a', 'key_b': 'b', 'key_c': 'c'}
```

Note: This works for python3.7 or above.

The reason is stated in the comments by [*@MisterMiyagi*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi).

Comment: This is only guaranteed to provide the expected result since Python 3.7. Prior to this, dictionary key order is not guaranteed (though it is de-facto ordered on CPython3.6 and PyPy3).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Agreed, I should add that detail to my answer. Adding it right now.

Comment: Note that `zip` iterates for its shortest iterable.

Comment: Why the downvote you too posted the same answer? I would love to know the reason for downvoting @BoseongChoi

Comment: It's not same. Your answer is for overwriting not updating. I think you can change `dict` to `my_dictionary.update`.

Comment: I just posted this as an alternative to all the answers posted it's up to OP discretion on which answer to choose. If OP wants to update in-place he can use `.update`, if he wants different dictionary he can use `dict(zip(...))` @BoseongChoi

Comment: @Ch3steR Oh, I am sorry. I concluded too early so I didn't realize that your answer could be applied that way. I canceled downvote. Have a nice day, too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your dictionary order is guaranteed or you don't care the order.

You can use built-in function `zip`.

It is very useful function to iterate two different *iterables*.

documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

```py
my_dictionary = {
    'key_a': '',
    'key_b': '',
    'key_c': '',
}

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for key, item in zip(my_dictionary, my_list):
    my_dictionary[key] = item

print(my_dictionary)
```

output:
`{'key_a': 'a', 'key_b': 'b', 'key_c': 'c'}`

Comment: ps. Please be careful with built-in `dict`'s order.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6.

Comment: That is a exactly what I was trying to find! Thank you very much :) And about the dictionary order: recently I've discovered that, but the order matters to me in this case only cause I needed to put each list element inside an especific dict key - after that, the dict's order doens't care anymore

Comment: @Ch3steR That's not problem in my answer.

Comment: If `my_dictionary` was longer than `my_list`, it breaks original keys if reassign dictionary. As I commented, using `my_dictionary.update` can solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
i = 0
for key in my_dict:
      my_dict[key] = my_list[i]
      i+=1
```

> Output : {'key_a': 'a', 'key_b': 'b', 'key_c': 'c'}

Comment: According to PEP 234, use `my_dict` instead of `my_dict.keys()`

Comment: Though the output does not change. I have edited according to your suggestion.

Comment: Actually, that was the first thing I did! But i thought the "i = 0 ... i += 1" did not smell exactly like Python. My last idea i've come was like use the "reverse()" function to reverse the List and use the "pop()" function to pop each one of the list's element inside the dictionary. But I thought that wasn't smelling good or very readable

Comment: What do you mean : 'does not smell like python'. :D If you want 1 line solution try dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: @NishantAgarwal sorry If I seemed rude or something bad like that. I was only trying to say that I've thought that was a built-in solution or something more complicated that I did not knew (cause I'm a Python beginner)

Comment: @NishantAgarwal also, thank you very much for your awnser and your tips. You were very helpful :)

Comment: Glad you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

my_dict = {
    'key_a' : '',
    'key_b' : '',
    'key_c' : '',
}

for index, key in enumerate(my_dict):
    my_dict[key] = my_list[index]

print(my_dict)
```